# How can I access HTTP Cache in a C# class library?

Tags: c#, caching

How can I access HTTP Cache in a C# class library ?

Comment: Which cache are you talking about? The HTTPCache object? Processor cache, Windows Cache? Please be a little more specific in your question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is recommended that you use [`System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx) rather than `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache`, as [explained in this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/httpruntime-cache-vs-httpcontext-current-cache).

Additionally, while the article talks about performance, I've also had issues in the past where `HttpContext.Current` isn't always available when you'd expect it to be, especially when dealing with asynchronous handlers.

Another thing to note is that if you aren't accessing the cache in the context of an HTTP request, `HttpContext` won't help you, since there won't be a relevant context for you to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the ASP.NET cache, then you can use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache`.

[HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) can also be used the access the current request, response, etc.

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current will sometimes be null, depending on the implementation of the class library.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the HTTP cache using the System.Web.Caching namespace as detailed in this MSDN article: [System.Web.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)

Once you import the namespace there is a static accessor for the cache which you can reference. As long as the cache has been instantiated prior (by the ASP.NET process, or another initiator) you will have access to the cache, otherwise it will return a NULL reference.